# how to get background.js to change based on options.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently making a Google Chrome extension, and in the options I want the user to be able to choose between it being always on or only activating when clicked. To do this, I need an options.js and a background.js file, which I have. However, I am having a lot of trouble getting them to communicate properly. I tried using the chrome.storage api, but it won't do anything.

Here is my code for background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {    
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": tabs[0].url}, function(response));
  });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {   
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            // console.log(tabs.length);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": tabs[0].url}, function(response) {});
        });
    }
});
```

And here is my code for options.js:

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var behavior = document.getElementById('behavior').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    extensionBehavior: behavior
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved!';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 1000);
  });
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  // Use default value color = 'red' and likesColor = true.
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    extensionBehavior: 'onClick'
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('behavior').value = items.extensionBehavior;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
    save_options);
```

If the behavior is set to "onClick", I only want the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` portion to be executed. If the behavior is set to 'alwaysOn', then I only want the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` portion to be executed. As far as debugging goes, both of those chunks work the way they're supposed to. I just need to know how to get one or the other to run based on the current options.

Answer (score 0):

For the communication between option and background, it would be quite easy when you choose the localStorage to pass info between them. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp